# TCP ports of Windows 10 PPTP VPN server

Tags: windows-10, vpn, tcp, pptp

I have installed the PPTP VPN server on Windows 10 machine (incoming connection feature), I have created the NAT on port TCP 1723 and UDP 1701 in the router.
In the server machine there was an apache webserver, listening on 80 and 443, then seems the the VPN services is overlapping the HTTPS 443 port.

Why VPN Server is listening at 443? Is there any way to disabled that port?
As far as I understand it is not mandatory because VPN is working also without the NAT of 443 port.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but please note that [PPTP is NOT SECURE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Tunneling_Protocol). It’s much better to use L2TP / IPSec (which has some issues but is generally more secure and supported by Windows by default) or OpenVPN.

Comment: Also, AFAIK PPTP only uses UDP port 1723 and the router needs to be able to forward protocol #47 (GRE). UDP port 1701 is one of the ports used for L2TP / IPSec. Port 443 is not used for either of these VPN protocols.

Comment: @StarCat thanks for your comment. I cannot understand how to choose the protocol in the VPN server service of Windows 10. I look like I can choose the protocol as client, but not as server. Can you confirm it? I have followed this tutorial and there is not protocol option: https://www.aitek.ch/how-to-set-up-a-vpn-server-on-windows-10/